Calculate the second derivative of the implicitly defined function $y = y (x)$ given by the equation $x^2 y - e^{2 y} = 0$.
Calculate the second derivative of the implicitly defined function $y = y (x)$ given by the equation $x^2 y - e^{2 y} = 0$, at the point $x = e$.
So I got this derivative:$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x y(x)}{x^2 -2e^{2y(x)}}$, and I got $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{(2y + 2x \frac{dy}{dx})(x^2 - 2e^{2y}) - (2x y)(2x - 4e^{2y} \frac{dy}{dx})}{(x^2 - 2e^{2y})^2}$.

What have you tried?

I tried calculating second derivative but i got a function with y(x) and i don't know how to get rid of it

Please edit the question to include the work you did and where you are stuck. Otherwise it gives the appearance that you expect someone here to solve the problem for you.

i included it sorry i am new

It seems like you are missing the $y$-coordinate of the point with $x=e$. Can you find that?

When $x=e$, can you guess a value of $y$ that works? Can you argue that is the only option?

yeah I guessed value of y=1 but i am little confused how to get second value of y and i am curious if there is a better method

What do you mean by “second value of $y$”?

there are two values which satisfies this equation with x=e it is (e, 1) and (e, 0.2031)

Ah, this is a poorly posed question. They should have specified the point of interest.

We have for a differential of an implicit  function
$$  \mathbf d F(x,y)  = \mathbf dy\ \partial_y F(x,y)+ \mathbf dx \ \partial_x F(x,y)$$
$\mathbf d F(x,y) = 0$ yields the direction of $F=\text{const}$. By the fact, that it is an equation between differentials, we get fractions with a negative sign. The derivative is
$$\frac{\mathbf dy}{\mathbf dy}= -\frac{\partial_x F}{\partial_y F} =- \frac{\left(\frac{d F}{dx}\right)}{\left(\frac{dF}{dy}\right)}$$
Formally, this is a Leibniz quotient of differentials with a cancellation of the  $\mathbf dF$ terms.
The second derivative follows by the obvious  d-rules
$$ \partial_x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{\partial_x F} {\left(\partial_y F\right)^2}  \  \partial_{xy}F - \frac{ \partial_x^2 F} {\partial_y F}$$
As an example consider
$$y=\frac{e^{\beta  x}}{\alpha }, \quad F(x,y)=\alpha  y-e^{\beta  x}$$
with
$$y''=\frac{\beta ^2 e^{\beta  x}}{\alpha }=\beta ^2 y$$
$$\frac{-\partial _{x,x} \left(\alpha  y-e^{\beta  x}\right)}{\partial _y.\left(\alpha  y-e^{\beta  x}\right)}+\frac{\partial _x \left(\alpha  y-e^{\beta  x}\right) \partial _{x,y} \left(\alpha  y-e^{\beta  x}\right)}{\left(\partial _y \left(\alpha  y-e^{\beta  x}\right)\right){}^2}= \frac{\beta ^2 e^{\beta  x}}{\alpha }$$
Your example yields
$$y''=\frac{2 y \left(x^2+2 e^{2 y}\right)}{\left(2 e^{2 y}-x^2\right)^2},\quad x^2 =\frac{e^{2 y}}{y}$$.
Expressions containing both variables $x,y$ with a transcendental dependence are open to the minimal art of representation
$$y''=\frac{2 e^{-2 y} y^2 (2 y+1)}{(1-2 y)^2}$$.
